# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 for non-digits

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

I am trying to create a simple program that reads a string of 4 digits, makes sure it is indeed 4 digits, makes sure there are no non-digits, then separates the first two digits from the last two and adds them together. I can make it all work but I still got this error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:`

This only happens when I try a string such as '456f'.

What can I change to fix this?

Code:

```
    s = input('please type a 4-digit integer \n')
valid = True
for c in s:
    if len(s)!= 4:
        valid = False
    if not c.isdigit():
        print (c, 'is not a valid input')
number = int(s)
firstOne = number // 100
secondOne = number % 100
sum = firstOne + secondOne
x = '/'
if valid == True:
    print('your integer is ' + str(number), x, 'first two digits are ' + str(firstOne), x, 'second two digits are ' + str(secondOne), x, 'sum of two new numbers is ' + str(sum))
else:
    print(len(s), 'is an invalid amount of digits')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's focus on this code:

```
for c in s:
    if len(s)!= 4:
        valid = False
    if not c.isdigit():
        print (c, 'is not a valid input')
number = int(s)
```

The first thing to say is that the `len()` check should be moved outside the character loop.

```
if len(s)!= 4:
    valid = False
for c in s:
    ...
```

The next comment to make is that whilst you are detecting non-digits, you continue executing code as if nothing is wrong. You presumably intend to set `valid` to `False`.

```
if not c.isdigit():
    print (c, 'is not a valid input')
    valid = False
```

Now, the main part of the problem. You need to skip the conversion to `int` when invalid input is detected.

```
if valid:
    number = int(s)
    ...
```

If you want to continue with such an approach your code would look like this:

```
valid = True
s = input('please type a 4-digit integer \n')
if len(s)!= 4:
    valid = False
    print(len(s), 'is an invalid amount of digits')

if valid:
    for c in s:
        if not c.isdigit():
            valid = False
            print (c, 'is not a valid input')

if valid:
    number = int(s)
    firstOne = number // 100
    secondOne = number % 100
    sum = firstOne + secondOne
    x = '/'
    print('your integer is ' + str(number), x, 'first two digits are ' + str(firstOne), x, 'second two digits are ' + str(secondOne), x, 'sum of two new numbers is ' + str(sum))
```

Having said all of that, I'd probably reorganise the code quite a bit to deal with the errors as soon as they are detected. Code is much easier to understand if you can organise your error handling that way.

```
s = input('please type a 4-digit integer \n')
if len(s)!= 4:
    sys.exit(str(len(s)) + ' is an invalid amount of digits')
for c in s:
    if not c.isdigit():
        sys.exit(c + ' is not a valid input')
number = int(s)
firstOne = number // 100
secondOne = number % 100
sum = firstOne + secondOne
x = '/'
print('your integer is ' + str(number), x, 'first two digits are ' + str(firstOne), x, 'second two digits are ' + str(secondOne), x, 'sum of two new numbers is ' + str(sum))
```

Now, that's a start in the right direction, but you can continue in this vein making the code better and better. [Sven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312546/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-for-non-digits#answer-9312611) gives you an excellent illustration of where such a process would ultimately lead.

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you very much. While your solution definitely seems to be the simplest, is there any way I could maintain the valid's and boolean logic in my code and still evade the error message?

Comment: @dustdustdust: If you think this answer is the most helpful one (I for one do think it is), consider to accept it.

Comment: @dustdustdust Sure. I've update the answer to really spell it out. But I can't stress enough that this is a bad solution. The fact this question exists at all shows the problems of `if` based error handling.

Comment: Thanks again! Yes, I understand that it is not the best way. I'm just looking for help to understand this concept, and now that it is much clearer, I will proceed to study the advanced answers of you and Sven. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You are checking whether all the characters are digits, but this check has no consequences -- you just carry on even when you found invalid characters.  This makes the code fail with the quoted error message.

I'd suggest to use a dedicated function to read the integer which repeats the query until it got a valid input:

```
def input_int_digits(prompt, digits=4):
    while True:
        s = input(prompt).strip()
        if len(s) == digits and s.isdigit():
            return int(s)
        print("Invalid input -- {}-digit integer expected.".format(digits))
```

Note that I used `str.strip()` to remove leading or trailing whitepsace and that `str.isdigit()` checks whether all characters of the string are digits -- you don't need to loop over the string.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
...
valid = len(s) == 4 and all(c.isdigit() for c in s)
if not valid:
    print (c, 'is not a valid input')
...
```

or even better (thanks, Sven!)

```
...
valid = len(s) == 4 and s.isdigit()
...
```

Comment: A handy shortcut for `all(c.isdigit() for c in s)` is `s.isdigit()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the for that checks for isdigit , you print an error message if the string contains non-digits but still call for int() on all s
you need to exit the program after "is not a valid input" message

you can change the print to

```
sys.exit("is not a valid input")
```